# Unable to retrieve custom order data on checkout step

Tags: cartthrob

I can capture custom order data as per the instructions at
http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/adding_custom_data_to_purchased_items_and_orders/ by using a field like this:

```
{exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form}
    <textarea name="delivery_note" id="txt-delivery-note" placeholder="Delivery note"></textarea>
{exp:cartthrob:customer_info}
```

That gets captured fine but I have a multi-step checkout and when you go back to the page this is on, I can't work out how to populate the field with the data that's been submitted.

It's on a page that has billing and shipping address fields and they all populate as expected but when I try to populate this custom data field as follows, the tag doesn't render:

```
<textarea name="delivery_note" id="txt-delivery-note" placeholder="Delivery note">{delivery_note}</textarea>
```

Any suggestions?

This is on EE 2.7.2, CT Pro 2.4.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried prefixing? e.g., `{order_delivery_note}` or `{customer_delivery_note}`?

Comment: Yep - neither variation are parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding custom_data[] to the name of your textarea.

```
{exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form}
    <textarea name="custom_data[delivery_note]" id="txt-delivery-note" placeholder="Delivery note"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
{/exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form}
```

Then when you're recalling the value use {custom_data:delivery_note}.

```
{exp:cartthrob:customer_info}
    <textarea name="custom_data[delivery_note]" id="txt-delivery-note" placeholder="Delivery note">{custom_data:delivery_note}</textarea>
{/exp:cartthrob:customer_info}
```

Comment: Chris, I tried to use {custom_data:delivery_note} on the order notification templates but although they get sent OK, I get a Template class error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the template class error you're receiving?
If you're using a {submitted_order_info} tag in your notification template, you should be able to use the short name of your delivery note field without the custom_data: prefix. Try using {delivery_note} instead of {custom_data:delivery_note} and see if the template class errors persist.